# COBOL - Perform para1 thru para1-exit VS Perform para1 thru para1

Tags: performance, cobol

I would like to know which is more efficient `PERFORM PARA1.` or `PERFORM PARA1 THRU PARA1-EXIT.`

```
PARA1.

    XXXXXX.

PARA1-EXIT.
    EXIT.
```

Comment: It depends on the compiler, but on those I was associated with there is no difference between PERFORM and PERFORM THROUGH.

Comment: probably the same, but it might vary on the compiler. Try testing it

Comment: If you really want to understand what is going on check this out: [COBOL Flow-of-Control](http://www3.sympatico.ca/bredam/TransferControl.html)

Comment: There is nothing 'too broad' whatsoever about this question. It is extremely specific. VTR

Answer (score 3):

Presumably for PARA1-EXIT, the code following it is not really executable code.  (I.e., it's something like an EXIT or CONTINUE)  Also presumably, there is no other control flow to PARA1-EXIT (other than similar PERFORM statements.)  Given that, using IBM Enterprise COBOL you can code it either way and get the same performance.  So you should code it based on local coding standards or clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example really doesn't make any sense based on how `PERFORM THRU` works.

`PERFORM X` will perform paragraph/section X and `PERFORM X THRU Z` will perform everything between X and Z. So if I have the following

```
PERFORM X000 THRU Z000

X000.
   some code
Y000.
   more code
Z000. 
   even more code
```

All 3 paragraphs will be performed. So saying `PERFORM X THRU X` conceptually makes no sense. It may compile (depending on the compiler), but at the day end of the day it seems like you should just use a `PERFORM X`. Without knowing exactly what compiler you are running, we can't really say exactly what `PERFORM X THRU X` will do, but the only thing that makes logical sense is that it is synonymous with `PERFORM X`.

I have seen code before that had `PERFORM X THRU X-EXIT`, but X-EXIT only ever contained an `EXIT` statement. There may be some historical reason why things were coded this way, but I don't see any reason to in modern COBOL development.

I would strongly recommend against using `PERFORM THRU` because if anyone were to ever add code between the two paragraphs and didn't notice it was a `PERFORM THRU`, you will run into issues.